# How to run functions concurrently in a Go API instead of sequential?

Tags: postgresql, go, concurrency

In an API, if we need to query multiple tables how can we achieve it concurrently instead of following the sequential way,
i.e

```golang
func sampleAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    a, err := getFromATable();  //1
    if err != nil {
       w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
       return
    }
    b, err := getFromBTable();  //2
    if err != nil {
       w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
       return
    }
    c, err := getFromCTable();  //3
    if err != nil {
       w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
       return
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to call the above functions 1,2,3 concurrently. How can I achieve that

Comment: *"I want to call the above functions 1,2,3 concurrently. How can I achieve that"* -- Use the [`go`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) keyword. See https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1.

Comment: @mkopriva I tried but had some issues related to it.

Comment: In that case you should have included the code you have tried and the issues you encountered, you should have explained why using just the `go` keyword was not enough. Also you should include what the desired output of `sampleAPI` should be considering the fact that its dependencies are executed concurrently. It is difficult to provide an appropriate solution to a problem for which we don't have the complete definition.

Comment: @mkopriva I will try from next time to write more detailed question so that it's easy for people to understand and answer. Though Currently, After going through the options available for the solutions(Go Routine,WaitGroup, ErrGroup), ErrGroup seems more reliable so I am going with that.

Answer (score 2):

### Using an error channel to synchronize

```golang
func sampleAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    chErr := make(chan error)

    var a correctType
    go func() {
        var err error
        a, err = getFromATable()
        chErr <- err
    }()

    var b correctType
    go func() {
        var err error
        b, err = getFromBTable()
        chErr <- err
    }()

    var c correctType
    go func() {
        var err error
        c, err = getFromCTable()
        chErr <- err
    }()

    var err error
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        if r := <-chErr; r != nil {
            err = r
        }
    }
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        // etc.
        return
    }

    // continue to do stuff with a, b, c
}
```

Some Notes:

- Every go function must add a value to `chErr`. Make sure of it! If there is no error, write `nil` to `chErr` (which this example does if there is no error).
- The for loop must iterate the same amount as there were go functions started.
- The for loop makes sure all functions have completed (with or without error) before continuing.
- Using the error to synchronise is convenient as it is the same type for all functions. The return type might be different. If we need to cancel on error, we need to get the error back out of the goroutines anyway.

### Using an `errgroup`

As suggested by @Зелёный in the comments, here an example using the (still) experimental package [errgroup](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup):

```golang
func sampleAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(context.TODO())

    var a correctType
    g.Go(func() (err error) {
        a, err = getFromATable(ctx)
        return err
    })

    var b correctType
    g.Go(func() (err error) {
        b, err = getFromBTable(ctx)
        return err
    })

    var c correctType
    g.Go(func() (err error) {
        c, err = getFromCTable(ctx)
        return err
    })

    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        // etc.
        return
    }

    // continue to do stuff with a, b, c
}
```

Some Notes:

- This one checks all errors and returns the first one for you.
- It also cancels the remaining calls if one errors out (hence the `ctx`)
- It uses a `sync.WaitGroup`
- Downside: it is an extra dependency as it is not part of the standard library (yet).

### Using a `WaitGroup`

You can also use a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait until all functions have returned their results.

```golang
func sampleAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)

    var a correctType
    var errA error
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        a, errA = getFromATable()
    }()

    var b correctType
    var errB error
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        b, errB = getFromBTable()
    }()

    var c correctType
    var errC error
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        c, errC = getFromCTable()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    
    if errA != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        // etc.
        return
    }
    if errB != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        // etc.
        return
    }
    if errC != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        // etc.
        return
    }

    // continue to do stuff with a, b, c
}
```

Some notes:

- You need 3 error variables here.
- You need to check all 3 error variables after `wg.Wait`, making it a bit verbose.

Comment: This has a goroutine leak: if it encounters an error, it returns immediately, and doesn't read the rest of the values from `chErr`. Since the channel is unbuffered, the goroutines will sit blocked trying to send to it forever.

Comment: Good catch. I will fix it.

Comment: There is https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup package, that much handy and clean than your code.

Comment: @Зелёный: Thank you for the hint. No need to downvote a valid solution though. Also note, that the package you are referring to is experimental and not part of the standard library (yet).

Comment: I didnt downvote. While it's experimental it much robust and less error prone than your code.

Comment: I think that is a matter of preference. In this case I'd rather not bring in another dependency. I'd not call my code "not robust". And it is as error prone (from the developers perspective) as using a WaitGroup, which would be the most common alternative.

Comment: @TehSphinX Can you help me understand the benefit of passing `ctx` in each function as I am new to Go Language and what will be the effect if I don't pass it?

Comment: That is a big topic. The `context` package was included in the standard library with go 1.7. One of its main usages is to abort things that take too long or are no longer needed. Lets look at http requests: In Go there are 2 functions to create a new request: `http.NewRequest` and `http.NewRequestWithContext`. The latter one has the advantage, that you can provide a context and then cancel the context or use a context with a timeout inside. As soon as the context gets cancelled, the request aborts. Generally: anything that can possibly take a long time is worth adding a ctx to.

Comment: Applying this to your use case: there is a context in every `*http.Request`. You can get it with `r.Context()`. If e.g. the client aborts the request, that context gets cancelled. If you pass that context on to e.g. the database functions, then you can stop them since their results are not needed anyway. They will then return an error saying `context called` or `context timeout exceeded`, etc.

You might want to generally read up on context yourself for example with: https://blog.golang.org/context

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the wait group in order to wait all the api call are finished before proceed like:

```
func sampleAPI(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var res1, res2, res3 myCustomType
    var err1, err2, err2 error

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(3)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        res1, err1 = getFromATable();  //1
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        res2, err2 = getFromBTable();  //2
    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        res3, err3 = getFromXTable();  //3
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Further reference also https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups and https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-waitgroup-tutorial/

Comment: You cannot add to the `WaitGroup` inside the goroutines. Always call `Add` before dispatching the goroutine, just like in the examples you cite.

Comment: The downvote could be due to this mistake?

Comment: @Matteo either that or due to the other typos/mistakes fixed already by other users.

Answer (score -2):

if a, b and c are different type, you can try the following approach. interface{} type is just to show how to code , you can modify channel type based on your requirement.

```
    aCh := make(chan interface{})
    bCh := make(chan interface{})
    cCh := make(chan interface{})
    defer close(aCh)
    defer close(bCh)
    defer close(cCh)
    
    go func() {
      a, _ := GetFromATable()
      aCh <- a
    }()
    go func() {
      b, _ := GetFromBTable()
      bCh <- b
    }()
    go func() {
      c, _ := GetFromCTable()
      cCh <- c
    }()

    fmt.Println(<- aCh, <- bCh, <- cCh)
```

if all three output are in same type, you can only need to use single channel or use forever for loop with select statement to handle streaming requirement.

Comment: This becomes a lot more complicated when also having to check the error in the main function. Also note, that closing a channel is not needed.

Comment: just respond to question coz no error handling is required in question :)

Comment: The questioner did not explicitely ask for it, right. Though from the code sample I gathered he wanted to know how to return (and handle) errors. Note: I did not downvote though. Never do.