# Calling multiple functions with different signatures concurrently

Tags: go

I'd like some feedback on the implementation details of what I'm trying to build. What I want to achieve is have multiple functions with different signatures that can be called concurrently.

Calling the functions in coroutines sequentially works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in a more idiomatic way, e.g. iterate over a slice of functions.

Since each function has different arguments and return values though, I have trouble figuring out what the best approach would be. An example that is a bit similar to my goal can be seen here: [Golang - How do you create a slice of functions with different signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314365/golang-how-do-you-create-a-slice-of-functions-with-different-signatures), but there the code just calls the functions and doesn't account for any return values.

Is what I have in mind even possible?

Comment: If you have return values, you have to handle each function call separately anyway. This sounds a lot like over-generalization. There are some languages that are made for this, Go is not one of them. You can parallelize different functions manually. No need to put them in a slice and iterate them.

Comment: Oh... and definitely don't use `reflect`.

Comment: See my answer here on how to run functions with different signatures and return values concurrently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65563745/how-to-run-functions-concurrently-in-a-go-api-instead-of-sequential/65563870#65563870

Answer (score 1):

You can use code from [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314365/golang-how-do-you-create-a-slice-of-functions-with-different-signatures) and just wrap the `v.Call(params)` into an anonymous function executing in its own goroutine like this:

```golang
...
// WaitGroup to wait on goroutines to finish their execution
var wg sync.WaitGroup
    
for a, v := range f {
    v := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    //calling the function from reflect
    val := reflect.ValueOf(f[a])
    params := make([]reflect.Value, v.NumIn())
    if v.NumIn() == 1 {
        params[0] = reflect.ValueOf(1564)
    } else if v.NumIn() == 2 {
        params[0] = reflect.ValueOf("Test FROM reflect")
        params[1] = reflect.ValueOf(float32(123456))
    }

    // Run them in parallel
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        val.Call(params)
    }()
}
wg.Wait()
```

See it on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RzDFzWVqkd4)

As for return values [`Value.Call()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call) returns `[]Value` which is slice of return values - so you are covered here too. Your question doesn't specify what you intend to do with results but given they will be generated in parallel you'll probably need to send them through a channel(s) - you can do that in anonymous function (after processing return slice) too.

Answer (score 0):

`go func() { MyPackage.MyFunc(with, whatsoever, signature); }()` - roughtly, that's what you need. You span as many goroutines (using the `go` keyword) as there are concurrent functions.

There is no notion of "returned value" from goroutine. For that you have to use `chan`nels. They are primary communication mechanism. So, you span a new goroutine with some function `f` of arbitrary signature and when it's done and you got some result, you send it to some channel **shared between goroutines for communication**.

Channels are thread-safe and were carefully designed to handle such a communication gracefully. Go, as programming language, provides few keywords that deal with reading/writing to/from channels. So there are pretty fundamental to (concurrent) programming in Go.

However, of course, you can handle it differently. Sharing some mutable memory protected by some kind of locking, or relying upon lockless `compareAndSet` fashion. Arguably, that's less idiomatic way and generally have to be avoided. Always prefer channels.